# vue-select select the option based on ipaddress

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I am trying to use this plugin https://github.com/sagalbot/vue-select

The issue with this is v-model gives the entire object unlike native select which is really a pain.

It is confirmed that the plugin does not support the option as outlined here https://github.com/sagalbot/vue-select/issues/122

The author suggests to use computed property for it. Here is the demo: http://jsbin.com/wedalog/8/edit?html,js,output

Here is the code:

```
Vue.component('v-select', VueSelect.VueSelect);

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    selected: null,
    options: [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "first_name": "Timothy Chavez",
      "ip_address": "20.153.187.10"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "first_name": "Harold Armstrong",
      "ip_address": "55.156.218.75"
    }, 
    {
      "id": 3,
      "first_name": "Randy Black",
      "ip_address": "79.135.200.161"
    }, 
    {
      "id": 4,
      "first_name": "Joshua Phillips",
      "ip_address": "146.153.135.116"
    }
    ]
  },
  computed: { 
    selectedIp() {
        return this.selected ? this.selected['ip_address'] : null
    }   
  }
});
```

and here is how it used in html:

```
<v-select v-model="selected" label="first_name" :options="options"></v-select>
```

It works but the answer is only valid while saving. Not sure what to do when loading? For example the `IpAddress` which I get from the server is `20.153.187.10` How would I then the appropriate option?

I am not sure why the author ignored this for something as basic as this.

Is there any more hack to make it work which would work for saving as well as loading?

Comment: You'll probably need to show some code for us to help.

Comment: @webnoob: Added the code from jsbin.

Answer (score 3):

You will need to use getOptoinLabel and make sure you're using latest vue-select cause i'm not sure on which version that prop was added. So in reference to your example.You will add this to your code:

```
methods: {
   getLabel: function(val){
     if(typeof val === 'object'){
         return val.first_name;
     }else {
     return this.options.filter(function(option){
            return option.ip_address === val;
        })[0].first_name;
     }
   }
}
```

And on the component instance add the prop `:get-option-label="getLabel"`

`<v-select :get-option-label="getLabel" v-model="selected" label="first_name" :options="options"></v-select>`

Note that the above function by default will have the argument val as the option you passed i.e in this case the v-model. So in your case it will be the ip address and all you need to do is then filter through your options the way you like and return the name.

Comment: Are you sure you are using the same plugin? This is the documentation https://sagalbot.github.io/vue-select/ I don't see anything as :get-option-label

Comment: The docs are kinda old, but yeah i'm using same plugin. Look into the [source code line 468](https://github.com/sagalbot/vue-select/blob/master/src/components/Select.vue#L468)

Comment: Thanks. That explains it. Do you know when would the value based on the ID be available? At the moment it gives entire object I need something like this https://github.com/sagalbot/vue-select/issues/122 if this plugin doesn't support then any other would work as well. It has now become too complicated and I believe I am doing the things which the plugin is expected to do but sadly I will have to implement all these hacks. Any ideas please?

Comment: I would just use an if else to check if we have an object as the value. You will usually get the ID only if you passed it yourself to the v-model. e.g when you set the selected value to '20.33.44.55'. I updated the answer to reflect that. Honestly I had to use v-select in my project and what I did I modified the source code the way I like the component to be.